# is it possible to print an image with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing

Ok, so I'm trying to print from a webpage (the typical "print" button, but I don't want the print dialog to appear) so I decided to use my already existing node.js backend to do the task (mainly because printing from browser is nearly impossible without the printing dialog).

I found the node-printer (https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) module, and it works great, but only with text. I tried to send RAW data, but what it does is printing the raw characters. What I actually need is to print a logo, along with some turn information (this is for a customer care facility).

Also, the printer must be installed locally, so I can't use IPP.

Is there any way to print an image, or a combination of images and text with node.js? can it be done through node-printer or is there another way?

Comment: node-printer calls `lpr` on posix with hardcoded arguments, so I don't  think you will be able to print images with it.

Comment: Are you trying to print to a printer that the client browser is connected to?  Or print to a printer that the node.js server is connected to?

Comment: node.js server will be running on the client machine also (is a system for printing turns)

Comment: If you create local web app may be will useful to switch on [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended calling an exe to do the work for me. I use a child_process to call [printhtml](http://www.printhtml.com/), which does all the printing work for me. My code ended this way:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('printhtml.exe file=file.html', function(err, data) {  
    console.log(data.toString());                       
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can print image using `node-printer`. This work for me

```
var Printer = require('node-printer');
var fs = require('fs');

// Get available printers list 
var listPrinter = Printer.list();

// Create a new Pinter from available devices 
var printer = new Printer('YOUR PRINTER HERE. GET IT FROM listPrinter');

// Print from a buffer, file path or text 
var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('PATH TO YOUR IMAGE');
var jobFromBuffer = printer.printBuffer(fileBuffer);

// Listen events from job 
jobFromBuffer.once('sent', function() {
    jobFromBuffer.on('completed', function() {
        console.log('Job ' + jobFromBuffer.identifier + 'has been printed');
        jobFromBuffer.removeAllListeners();
    });
});
```

Comment: For node printer you have installed python as well as Visual Studion(if windows) right?

Comment: `listPrinter` is empty in my case though I have installed printers. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had success with the Node IPP package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp.

The example code on the docs, which uses another node module PDFKIT to convert  your html/file into a PDF, does not work. See my answer here: [Cannot print with node js ipp module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610735/cannot-print-with-node-js-ipp-module) for a working example.