# Cannot print with node js ipp module

Tags: node.js

I have a pritter connected via USB port to my PC. I run Windows 7.

Here is simple code:

```
var ipp=require('ipp')
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('filename.pdf', function(err, data) { 
  if (err)
    throw err;

  var printer = ipp.Printer("http://localhost/ipp/printer");
  var msg = {
    "operation-attributes-tag": {
      "requesting-user-name": "William",
      "job-name": "My Test Job",
      "document-format": "application/pdf"
    },
    data: data
  };
  printer.execute("Print-Job", msg, function(err, res){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

**How can i resolve my local priter address to write it here:**

```
var printer = ipp.Printer("http://localhost/ipp/printer");
```

**?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite an old question but I've just resolved my own issues with this module.

Working example:

```html
var ipp = require("ipp");
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

var buffers = [];
doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
doc.on('end', function () {

    console.log(Buffer.concat(buffers));

    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://192.168.1.50:631", {version:'1.0'});
    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag":{
            "requesting-user-name": "User",
        "job-name": "Print Job",
        "document-format": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        data: Buffer.concat(buffers)
    };

    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        console.dir(res);
    });
});
 doc.end();
```

The newer version of IPP requires you to format your data into a stream, despite the current example on the IPP github page.

You'll have to play around with the settings: the **printer URL**, the **version parameter** (1.0 or 2.0 depending on your printer) and importantly the **document-format**.

**Running the following will log out your printer's details if a connection is made which could provide further insight if you continue to have issues:**

```html
var ipp = require("ipp");
var printer = ipp.Printer('http://192.168.1.50:631', { //your printer's IP with the IPP port (631) appended
    version: '1.0' //try 1.0 or 2.0
});

printer.execute('Get-Printer-Attributes', null, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Nice! After running the Get-Printer-Attributes i discovered that i had to send a print job over with a uri like this: *ipp://192.168.168.160:631/ipp/print*. IE over ipp and not http