# convert PDF data into octet-stream for printer autodetection

Tags: mime-types, printers, network-printers

I have a printer that only accepts application/octet-stream over IPP. My program downloads binary PDF data and I need to convert that into application/octet-stream, which would (supposedly) let the printer decide what to print. However, when I send the data, it just prints binary data as text and not as formatted PDF. I'm using node with npm package 'ipp'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to that, in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33610735/)! I found a working example that, I modified a little like this to work (mixed some with the [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit)! example, but shorted).

Here is my working version  (node v16.17.0 | npm 8.15.0 | windows 11)

```js
var ipp = require("ipp");
var concat = require("concat-stream");
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const doc = new PDFDocument();

// Pipe its output somewhere, like to a file or HTTP response
// Render some text
doc
  .fontSize(25)
  .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);

// Add an image, constrain it to a given size, and center it vertically and horizontally
doc.image('./my-image.png', {
  fit: [250, 300],
  align: 'center',
  valign: 'center'
});
  doc.pipe(concat(function (data) {
    //I used this url with a Brother printer, because the 631 port had some weird problem
    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://<ip address>:80/ipp",{version:'2.0'});
    
    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag":{
            "requesting-user-name": "User",
        "job-name": "Print Job",
        "document-format": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        data: data
    };

    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        //in case of error
        console.log("Error: ",err);
        console.log('res',res);
    });
}));

//This last line is very important!
doc.end();
```

note that the version you have to check if your printer supports it

I checked that with this code: (I lost the link where I found this, so that is why there is not reference to it)

```js
var ipp = require('ipp');
var uri = "http://<ip address>:80/ipp";
var data = ipp.serialize({
    "operation":"Get-Printer-Attributes",
    "operation-attributes-tag": {
        "attributes-charset": "utf-8",
        "attributes-natural-language": "en",
        "printer-uri": uri
    }
});
 
ipp.request(uri, data, function(err, res){
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res,null,2));
})
```